# MySQL connection limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with reaching my connection limit too quickly... Am I right in thinking the following will help resolve this?

On older files using mysql_query

```
<?php
mysql_close($link);
if (isset($link2)) {
    mysql_close($link2);
}
?>
```

On newer files using mysqli class

```
class DB extends MySQLi {
  function __destruct() {
    $this->close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create multiple connections in the first place?:)

Comment: `Am I right in thinking` - check it in practice, it's your scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection is closed automatically when script finishes it's work even if you forget to `mysql_close()`. Consider raising max_clients setting `my.cnf`

Also, if you are using only one database, you wont need, you don't need two connections - use one instead.

Comment: I am using two databases, though it varies from script to script. So problem would be quantity of queries rather than connections you think then?

Comment: @John Smith, yes, if you have many heavy queries, this means the connection is open for some time. Less queries mean less busy connections.

Answer (score 1):

You may also be keeping connections open via persistent connections (pconnect), causing your database server to pool and stack up the connections.  I've had troubles with this up until about PHP5.2?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 mysql_close($link);
 if (isset($link2)) {
     mysql_close($link2);
 }
 ?>
```

This doesn't make any sense - if know that both variables may contain mysql connection resources then close the both!

Better yet - if your code is a mess and you can't make sense of it, then...

```
<?php
@mysql_close();
@mysql_close();
@mysql_close();
?>
```

But the only place you can sensibly put this (without analysing the code behaviour in some details - in which case you would *know* what resources you have open) is at the end of the script - which is where the connections get closed **anyway**.

Similarly, the destruct method is only called when all references to an object are deleted - this is marginally better but depending on the code structure you may get no benefit at all.

It makes far more sense to identify which URLs are taking a long time to process and trying to re-factor the code (both PHP and SQL) in these.